# Getting TypeError: $.widget is not a function Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, javascript

I am getting a JavaScript type error in **Minicart, Product view page**, and **Checkout page**.

```
TypeError: $.widget is not a function
           $.widget('mage.priceBox')
           $.widget('mage.dataPost')
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you run deploy command?

Comment: Yes i am run deploy command but still getting error.

Comment: you have to first remove pub/static folder content after you have to run command for deploy

Comment: Hi Rakesh Any command to remove pub/static folder using command.

Comment: you have to remove manually

Comment: Remove pub/static files using grunt command -  grunt clean:<themename> exec:<themename>

Comment: did this work???

Comment: did you got any solutions for this? I am facing same problem. If you found any then please post here.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem using Porto Theme. In my case sometimes jQuery was recognized, sometimes not. Unfortunately, I didn't understand the cause, but I found a solution.

**In short: Merge all javascript files.**

1. In Backend go to:

`Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings`

2. Activate:

   - Enable JavaScript Bundling
   - Merge JavaScript Files
   - Minify JavaScript Files (Optional)
3. Irecommendedened to deploy the static files

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

4. Clear cache under `System -> Cache Management`

   - In `Additional Cache Management` region choose the Button `Flush CSS/Javascript Cache`
   - And `Flush Magento Cache` afterwards

**Now clear Cache in Browser and reload.**

For developing this solution is not satisfying, but at least for productive, use it should be a good working solution, without unpredictable behavior.

Hope it helps..

Comment: that helped me, thank you. I had the same issue

Comment: I only did the CSS/Javascript & Magento Cache flush, and worked, but your answer can help other cases ! In dev env. we are bound to leave the JS optimizations disabled, debugging becomes hard otherwise, and also rarely use the deploy command, the page refresh triggers this static file generation. Thank you !

Comment: I think this has something to do with requirejs-config.js ... sometimes `map: { '*': {` is used, and sometimes `paths: {` ...

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well but then I ran across this article: http://www.danjoseph.me/2016/09/16/magento-2-widget-not-function/

In the article he explains that jquery was being loaded a second time on the page and therefore overwriting the version loaded previously by magento. For me it was a marketing script that was also loading jquery for some reason. jQuery should only be loaded once in the head by this tag and all others should be removed.

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://seatup.local/pub/static/frontend/Seatup/theme/en_US/jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score -4):

Go to your theme folder and locate the following file in **Magento_Theme** folder

> default_head_blocks.xml

and replace

`<script src="jquery.js" />`

with

```
<remove src="jquery.js" />
```

Make sure you clean the cache and refresh the page.

I had the same issue and got it resolved using above method.

Comment: Doing this you are removing jQuery. It's true that solves the error described on the question but now other things are broken for example related of bootstrap. `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6`

Comment: Removing jQuery is not the correct way to handle this. It is bad advise.