# Lots of jQuery conflicts on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, jquery, conflict

I'm working on a new Magento 2 installation with the Porto theme and have noticed that when you first visit the site or have the browser cache disabled you get a lot of of jQuery conflict errors. Below are examples of these errors from both the theme and core Magento2.

**examples:**

```
(index):394     Uncaught TypeError: $(...).swMegamenu is not a function
dataPost.js:13  Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
```

When I look how these jQuery functions are being initiated, I see it's using requireJs correctly to load jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu'
    ], function ($) {
        $(".sw-megamenu").swMegamenu();
    });
</script>
```

**AND**

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "mage/template",
    "jquery/ui"
], function($,mageTemplate){

    $.widget('mage.dataPost', {......
```

I can fix it by adding `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` at the beginning of the function block (but this seems redundant as `$` is already passed as a parameter to the function, it works though!)

Also, I can fix it by Merging all JS as suggested in answer to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122618/getting-typeerror-widget-is-not-a-function-magento-2).

Merging the JS seems to be a good fix but I'd like to better understand why this is happening and the best approach to solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well but then I ran across this article: http://www.danjoseph.me/2016/09/16/magento-2-widget-not-function/

In the article he explains that jquery was being loaded a second time on the page and therefore overwriting the version loaded previously by magento. For me it was a marketing script that was also loading jquery for some reason. jQuery should only be loaded once in the head by this tag and all others should be removed.

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://seatup.local/pub/static/frontend/Seatup/theme/en_US/jquery.js"></script>`